# Navigate if my var is not set in my redux state

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm making somme connexion/inscription screens. I have a profil bottom tab button. The goal is if the user click on it, It will either show his profil page if he is connected (I'm setting an user in my redux store), or show a Landing screen with the login button and subscribe button if he is not.

How can i navigate to this landing page every time the user click on "Profil" on my bottom tab bar if the redux store is empty ?

Here is my profil code :

```
// Screens / Profil.js

import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import { color } from "../constants/color";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

/*
 *   Class Profil
 *   Appears when the users click on the profil button in the bottom tab bar
 *   Return JSX component
 */
class Profil extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  // This is what I have tried so far
  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props.currentUser == null) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Landing");
    }
  }

  /*
   * Render the page
   * @param null
   * @return JSX component
   */
  render() {
    const { currentUser } = this.props;
    console.log(currentUser);
    if (currentUser == null) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
          <Text>You are not connected</Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
          <Text>Welcome {currentUser.user.username}</Text>
          <Button title="Déconnexion" onPress={this._disconnection} />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: color.whisper
  }
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    currentUser: state.connection.currentUser
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Profil);
```

So when I first click on my Profil it goes well on my landing page:

[image: Landing Page]

But if I click again on Profil, It does not show my landing page :

[image: This is not supposed to show]

I guess it's because the component did not rerender himself . How could i Handle a constant redirection according to my redux state var ?

UPDATE : My stack Navigator

```
const ProfilStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Profil: {
    screen: Profil,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Profil"
    }
  },
  Landing: {
    screen: Landing,
    headerMode: "none",
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },
  SignUp: {
    screen: SignUp,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Inscription"
    }
  },
  SignIn: {
    screen: SignIn,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Connection"
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: so what do you get?

Comment: I'm affraid I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: do you get errors?

Comment: No nothing, it just that i want my var (this.props.currentUser) which is a redux store var, to be checked every time the user go on that page and get a redirection if it's empty. Actually it only works when the user visit my screen the first time, because the component does mount so the verification does occur, but not if the user go on this page again

Comment: when you log `this.props.currentUser` what do you get?

Comment: I got null when i'm not connected, And i got the user informations If i do connect before going on that page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two options to solve this, the first one is using [NavigationEvents](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) and the second one is [navigationOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#bottomtabnavigatorconfig)

**First option**, add `didFocus` listener to your profile component, which will get fired when profile tab is focused.

```
class Profil extends React.Component {

  subscribe = null;

  constructor(props){}

  focused = () => {
    if (this.props.currentUser == null) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Landing');
    }
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.subscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', this.focused);
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.subscribe && this.subscribe.remove();
    this.subscribe = null;
  }

  render() {
   ...
  }
}
```

**Second option**, with `navigationOptions` add `tabBarOnPress` which gets fired when you click the tabbar.

```
Profil: {
  screen: ProfilStackNavigator,
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: 'Profil',
    tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
      // console.log('Pressed');
      defaultHandler();
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully done this. 
You have the correct idea.

Perhaps your navigation object is the issue?

Here is an example I coded for a 3D Earthquake Visualizer with React/Redux/Three. I passed the history object as a prop to my components and used that to dynamically change the routing. (not included in example)

I would suggest ensuring your router API is correct and then logging the state on will mount lifecycle.

I hope this has been helpful. Good Luck! :)

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
      ...
      quakes: state.viz.quakes,
      ...
   };
};


componentDidMount(){
   // if data hasn't download redirect to splash
   if (this.props.quakes[this.props.feedIndex].length === 0) {
     this.props.history.push("/"); 
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Your exemple seems a lot like mine, I dont know what to change ? I'm actually glad you're saying this is the right approach ! I guess the problem is once the first redirection occured, the "Profil" component is mounted so it does not enter in my componentDidMount() again if i go back on this screen, and just render the page